# Is there a better way to organize this React page with an async call to the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `useEffect` that should only run once. Hence I have set `router.query.something` as a dependency. The request must wait for `router.query.something` to be hydrated, then it only makes the request if the value is truthy.

This just seems like an overly-complicated function to make a simple one-time request to the API, but I haven't figured out a cleaner way to do it.

```
const MyPage = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      if (router.query.something) {
        const res = await api.get(`/resetTokens/${router.query.something}`)
        setUser(res.data)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setUser(null)
    }
  }, [router.query.something])

  return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

Normally, I would use `getServerSideProps`, but in this situation, I can't, because the request is setting a cookie. If I use `getServerSideProps` the cookie doesn't pass through to the client.

Comment: This looks fine. one suggestion is to move your entire try catch inside your if block .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note two things.

First, `useEffect` should not be using `async` functions. There should be a warning in the console regarding your use of `async` in `useEffect`.

Secondly, you should be cleaning up the `useEffect` since you are dealing with promises. If you do not clean up you may encounter memory leaks which can cause unexpected results.

Your code should look something like this instead

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;
  if (router.query.something) {
      api.get(`/resetTokens/${router.query.resetToken}`)
     .then(res=> {
        if(!isMounted) return;
        setUser(res.data)
     })
     .catch(e => {
        if(!isMounted) return;
        setUser(null)
     });
      
  }
 
  return () => {
    isMounted = false;
  };
  }, [router.query.something])
```

You could also try doing this with `AbortController`. Academind has a good blog explaining what is happening and how to fix. https://academind.com/tutorials/useeffect-abort-http-requests/

Answer (score 1):

```js
const MyPage = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();

        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = fetch(`/resetTokens/${router.query.resetToken}`, { signal: abortController.signal });
                setUser(res.data)
            } catch (e) {
                setUser(null)
            }
        };
        
        if (router.query.something) {
            fetchData();
        }

        return () => {
            abortController.abort();
        };
    }, [router.query.something]);

    return (<div>...</div>)
}
```